# category axis and Value axis title in kendo bar chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am working with kendo bar chart/ column chart, I am displaying the category axis and value axis title in x and Y axis, i am able to see the title being set.

The issue is the title is very close to the lines of x and y axis, Is there any way i can provide some spacing between the title and the lines in bar chart?

Help needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `labels.margin` property in chart config. Here is [API Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.labels.margin.).